# Create a virtual layer with a project variable defining the source layer(s) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer, qgis-variable

I would like to create a virtual layer where the source layer can easily be changed by editing the value of a project variable. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM var('active_layer')
```

I found [this post](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35867) at github, but it seems that the function var() only works for setting fields but not for selecting the source layer.

Is it somehow possible to select the source layer(s) of a virtual layer by using values from project variables?

Comment: What is the source? (e.g. geopackage, postgresql)

Comment: I think that is currently not possible. But you could write a Python expression function that exchanges the data source of the layer.

Comment: @David Galt: The type of the source is Geopackage